# Variants of Bilinear Diffie-Hellman Assumption

Tags: elliptic-curves, reference-request, pairings, group-theory

Could someone point me to the paper/reference where the following variant of q-strong Bilinear Diffie-Hellman assumption was used?

Given $s \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ and $g, g^{\frac{1}{s}}, g^{s}, g^{s^2}, \ldots, g^{s^q}$ it is difficult to compute $g^{\frac{1}{s + c}}$ for $c \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*\setminus \{-s\}$.

Essentially, I am looking for the variant which has $g^{\frac{1}{s}}$ as a part of the public parameter.

Comment: What is $q-$strong? Is $q=p$?

Comment: @kodlu Actually $q$ and $p$ are completely independent. $p$ is the order of the group and $q$ is the maximum exponent of the secret parameter $s$.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, this hard assumption is introduced by Boneh and Boyen in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-28628-8_3.pdf).

But I don't think so the assumption that you mention being hard, because $c=0$ is a simple solution for it. Then the element $g^{\frac{1}{s}}$ should not publish. Also, this assumption is not bilinear because the challenge is an element in the cyclic group of $\mathbb{G}$ and it is not $e(g,g)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+c}}$.

Comment: There is no obvious attack when $c \neq 0$. 
As mentioned in the question: $c \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*\setminus \{-s\}$.

I am having a hard time recollect the reference and whether it is hard to break $g^{\frac{1}{s + c}}$ or $e(g, g)^{\frac{1}{s + c}}$.

Comment: @Shravan I am not sure about the proof of security of your claim, but by issuing $g^{\frac{1}{s}}$ we know the Diffie-Hellman Inversion (DHI) will break. Meanwhile, I think if you are convinced then you can introduce a new assumption. :) I found a new version of the mentioned paper, take a look at it. http://theory.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/bbsigs.pdf